# mockito in gradle not working for java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, mockito, build.gradle

I have a basic java project and I want to run tests using Mockito (since I use it at work and it's easy). So I referred to [this](http://mockito.org) link and added the following to my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
}
```

Even though I think mavenCentral() should be enough, I went ahead and added these to my repositories list

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

The ./gradlew clean build runs perfectly fine, but when I try to add the import for Mockito it doesn't get it. And my External Libraries folder in the project doesn't have the Mockito jar. I even tried using mavenLocal() in the hope that it'll pick it up from my local .m2 directory, but it doesn't. I've been looking around and trying out all combinations for 2 hours now with absolutely no result. I don't want to add the jar to the project. I want to let gradle pull it from the central repo and compile it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: So basically it's not question about gradle itself but rather about the IDE you use? If so, add better tagging for this question.

Comment: Not really. If it were just gradle then it should have run fine from the my terminal, which it didn't. It showed the same error on the terminal too. I am still not sure why the ./gradle build OR assemble not add the jar to the class path. The point around the IDE was to give all the information I know to assist others to answer better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html) Apparently clicking on that refresh button refreshes the dependencies. Else right click on module -> Open Module settings -> Go to Dependencies tab and add your dependency either from your local m2 folder or provide the maven central URL for the dependency. 
I was too used to Eclipse doing stuff for me I guess. :)

Comment: Yeah working with the idiosyncrasies is often the most trying!  Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

Is this in Eclipse?  If so, right-click on the project and go `gradle > Update All` (I think it is - I don't have open at moment and don't think about it any more).  This will update the dependencies.

Comment: Also, f I comment out the junit line from my build.gradle it throws an error on all the tests currently written. So I believe there is nothing wrong with the gradle per se but i am still not sure why mockito won't get downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @HankCa it helped me look in that direction :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring those libraries other than test package, that is main package you will get this error.

Because you provided scope    **`testCompile`**    in    **`build.gradle`**, so these libraries are available only in test package.

So, change   **`testCompile`**  to **`compile`** in build.gradle.